# Large space between tables

Tags: tables

I'm in the middle of creating a lot of tables, but I've run into a problem. When I add more than 3 tables in a row, a space between the tables are suddently created.

I created a few copies of the following table, they are generated tough some excel add-in:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
    \hline
    \textit{(1,000,000)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{MV} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{TP} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ST} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{RP} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Mean  & 227,799 & 284,627 & 234,909 & 290,288 \bigstrut[]\\
    Std Dev & 28,711 & 33,111 & 29,954 & 35,171 \\
    Default & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 \bigstrut[]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:test}
   \caption{Add caption}
\end{table}
```

Preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{Pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\raggedbottom



\begin{document}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

[image: Page1]
[image: Page1]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle adding ragged bottom does not changed anything neither does removing h, I added the preamble, but I dont really have anything there

Comment: no that's because I guessed wrong (it is hard to guess the markup just from an image of the output:-) `article` is  raggedbottom by default, so the issue is not my guess (I will delete the comment) the issue is as @Mico says

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest that you add the following instructions to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength\@fptop{0pt}             % default: '0\p@ \@plus 1fil'
\setlength\@fpsep{2\baselineskip}  % default: '8\p@ \@plus 2fil'
\makeatother
```

This code governs the spacing above and between floats on floats-only pages.

`2\baselineskip` means: insert vertical whitespace in the amount of `2\baselineskip` between floats on a floats-only page; you're obviously free to either increase or decrease this amount.

Comment: This did fix the 2nd page, but there is still a big space between page 1 and 2, where one more table could easily be fitted?

Comment: changing the baseline setting only seems to affect the tables on page 2

Comment: @DennisChristiansen - The permissible number of floats on a single page is controlled by the counter `totalnumber`; its default value is `3`. (In case you're curious: By default, 2 floats are allowed at the top and 1 is allowed at the bottom.) I can suggest adding the following code to the preamble: `\setcounter{topnumber}{3} \setcounter{bottomnumber}{2} \setcounter{topnumber}{5}`.

Comment: Hmm this still only shows 3 tables on the first page and then 5 on the rest. But I found a solution myself, by using \usepackage{float} and then "H" I was able to show 5 tables on the first page as well.